# Prevent volume keys from changing both ALSA master volume and Ubuntu volume

Tags: sound, keyboard, alsa, volume-control

I'm running Ubuntu 21.10 on a desktop PC with an external USB sound card and a gaming keyboard with a wheel for volume control (which I think just fires "volume up/down" key events when moved and should be equivalent to regular volume keys).

When I move the wheel, the "speaker" icon notification appears and the displayed volume level changes in small steps as desired. However, in `alsamixer`, I can see that wheel input also changes "Master" level for my sound card as following compared to the level displayed in the notification:

- ~95% displayed level -> ALSA "Master" is ***0*** -> no audio output at all
- ~99% -> ***45*** -> very loud audio
- 100% -> ***100*** -> extremely loud audio

How can I prevent ALSA levels from reacting to keyboard input so I can set them to a fixed level and only use keyboard input to set volume as displayed in the notification?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open configuration for device, e.g. `sudo vim /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf`
2. Apply line `volume = ignore` in section `[Element Master]`
3. Restart audio server: `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`